# Irregular sampling of an image using OpenGL

Tags: opengl, image-processing, filter

I'm looking for some pointers on how to sample an image using OpenGL at a list of specified locations. Any links to tutorial or examples similar to the problem below?

At the moment we have a code that calculates the 'output intensity' at a list of specified locations *`x1,y1, x2,y2, ..., xn,yn`* applying a Lanczos2 filter to an input image. The amount of locations at the moment is 20 (which is actually the list of phosphene locations in a visual prosthesis) but it will eventually increase up to 256 and GPU processing will certainly accelerate things. The list of locations can't be hardcoded.

So far I have seen how to implement a median filter and alike, but in my case there is no need to compute the convolution with the filter kernel at every image pixel, just at the locations specified.

Comment: Do you mean OpenGL or OpenCL (or CUDA)? The later one maybe better if you don´t have a Task strictly related to OpenGL rendering etc...

Comment: OpenGL only. OpenGL ES 2.0 will be ideal.

Comment: Is your goal to create a new image, resampled from the original using these locations as offsets from each pixel?

Comment: The goal  is to create an array that has the output intensities at the sample locations

Comment: I can't really see how you're hoping to harness the benefits of using the GPU to just return the values from particular locations in an image. Is the image already in GPU memory? Will the resulting array be used by something running on the GPU? If the answer to the first of these questions is "no" then there is nothing to be gained by loading the whole image to GPU memory just to use relatively few of the values.

Answer (score 0):

Handle those values (intesity) in a second texture that has a sample or not bit.

Answer (score 0):

If you use OpenGL, you'll be able to define the ROI (region of interest), the portion of an image to which you want to apply edits or processing, as you describe.

If you go that route, this is how you calculate the median in a pixel neighborhood radius of your choosing using OpenGL ES 2.0/3.0:

```
kernel vec4 medianUnsharpKernel(sampler u) {
vec4 pixel = unpremultiply(sample(u, samplerCoord(u)));
vec2 xy = destCoord();
int radius = 3;
int bounds = (radius - 1) / 2;
vec4 sum  = vec4(0.0);
for (int i = (0 - bounds); i <= bounds; i++)
{
    for (int j = (0 - bounds); j <= bounds; j++ )
    {
        sum += unpremultiply(sample(u, samplerTransform(u, vec2(xy + vec2(i, j)))));
    }
}
vec4 mean = vec4(sum / vec4(pow(float(radius), 2.0)));
float mean_avg = float(mean);
float comp_avg = 0.0;
vec4 comp  = vec4(0.0);
vec4 median  = mean;
for (int i = (0 - bounds); i <= bounds; i++)
{
    for (int j = (0 - bounds); j <= bounds; j++ )
    {
        comp = unpremultiply(sample(u, samplerTransform(u, vec2(xy + vec2(i, j)))));
        comp_avg = float(comp);
        median = (comp_avg < mean_avg) ? max(median, comp) : median;
    }
}

return premultiply(vec4(vec3(abs(pixel.rgb - median.rgb)), 1.0)); 
}
```

A brief description of the steps
1. Calculate the mean of the values of the pixels surrounding the source pixel in a 3x3 neighborhood;
2. Find the maximum pixel value of all pixels in the same neighborhood that are less than the mean.
3. [OPTIONAL] Subtract the median pixel value from the source pixel value for edge detection.

If you're using the median value for edge detection, there are a couple of ways to modify the above code for better results, namely, hybrid median filtering and truncated media filtering (a substitute and a better 'mode' filtering). If you're interested, please ask.